# Change color of selected toggle buttons using MUI ThemeProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to change the color of selected toggle buttons in an app using React, Typescript, and ThemeProvider from `@mui/material 5.11.13`.

When a toggle button is selected, it still has color #1976d2, which is the same as MUI's palette.primary.main color instead of the new theme color.

I've tried a few things without success, and the latest code is below. Any idea how to get it working?

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';

// these didn't work
// import { createTheme, ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
// import { createTheme, ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
// import { createTheme, ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const mui5 = {
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#ff0000',
            dark: '#ff0000',
            contrastText: '#ff0000',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#ff0000',
            dark: '#ff0000',
            contrastText: '#ff0000',
        },
    },
    components: {
        MuiToggleButton: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    '&.Mui-selected': {
                        color: '#000000',
                        background: '#ff0000',
                        backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
                    },
                    '&:hover': {
                        color: '#000000',
                        background: '#ff0000',
                        backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

const muiTheme = createTheme(mui5);

...

<MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything inherently wrong with the code posted. Please provide a codesandbox link with a minimal reproducible example of the issue if possible. In the meantime, here are a few suggestions:

1. Make sure your component is wrapped in your `ThemeProvider`.
2. Try removing the `color` prop from your `ToggleButton` component.
3. Increase the CSS specificity of your selected state via a class selector.

Comment: it may be a conflict with a peer dependency version of @mui. i uninstalled one and the peer dependency version is still installed, and it seems to work.